# Python: adding a dataclass object attribute that is dependent on other attribute in unique way for each object

Tags: python, attributes, python-dataclasses

Before I explain my issue, I will give example code that is an extremely simplified version of what I’m working with:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Input:
    # attributes unimportant here

    @classmethod
    def from_stdin(cls):
        return cls(something made from user inputs)


@dataclass
class Thing:
    thing_att_1: list  # data type is unimportant here


list_1, list_2 = some list, some other list


class Sys:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
        self.thing_1 = Thing(list_1)
        self.thing_2 = Thing(list_2)

    @classmethod
    def from_stdin(cls):
        return cls(Input.from_stdin())

    def calculate_list_1_alt(self):
        list_1_alt = do something with self.input and self.thing_1.thing_att_1
        return list_1_alt

    def calculate_list_2_alt(self):
        list_2_alt = do something different with self.input and self.thing_2.thing_att_1
        return list_2_alt


if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    Sys = Sys.from_stdin()
```

So here’s my issue: I would like to have a second attribute for Thing objects, say, thing_att_2, which would depend on thing_att_1 and the user input, but *how* it depends on them would be different for each Thing object.  The calculate functions under the Sys class return what I would want to have as those second attributes.  I can’t simply plug those calculate functions in when initializing the Thing objects because the functions refer to an attribute of the object that it hasn’t finished initializing yet.  I could just make another dataclass to contain these attributes separately, but I don’t like this because they truly are attributes of Thing objects (you’ll just have to trust me on that), and it will require clunkier code downstream.  Alternatively, I could make dataclass Thing with some sort of default value for thing_att_2, then just have some bare code to execute underneath name==main to alter those default values to what I need them to be, but I get the impression that that would be considered an ugly solution, and I don’t want to cause anyone reading my code to get sick.  So what can/should I do?